# How to find only updated contact's Identifier or Item in Contact Framework

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, contacts-framework

I'm using NSNotification `"CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification"` to notify when contacts updated. But how can I know exactly which contacts were updated ?

Comment: Every contact has a unique id , ON update that changed too , So save contacts in array , on update notification compare with new one.

Comment: Nope I checked that, ON update that's not gonna change ....

Comment: yes apple didn't recommend that , But check answer , Identifier property is also for CNContact

Comment: That doc about ABAddressBookAddRecord , I'm talking about Contact Frame work :)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContact_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015273-CH1-DontLinkElementID_42 check this , identifer property is here too.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but my point is when user change his phone number or email, this ID won't change, so again i need to refetch all the contacts item. No point of matching all the elements. I just need to find out what are the updated/deleted contacts :)

Comment: did you try printing [notification userinfo] ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108356/discussion-between-chathuranga-silva-and-mohammad-ishaq).

Answer (score 0):

The [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html) says

> After a save is successfully executed, the contact store posts a
>   CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification notification to the default
>   notification center. If you cache any Contacts framework objects you
>   need to refetch those objects, either by their identifiers, or with
>   the predicates that were used to originally fetch them, and then
>   release the cached objects. Note that cached objects are stale, but
>   not invalid.

From ios 9.0 [Documentation](http://If%20you%20cache%20the%20fetched%20contacts,%20groups,%20or%20containers,%20you%20need%20to%20refetch%20these%20objects%20(and%20release%20the%20old%20cached%20objects)%20when%20CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification%20is%20posted.)

> If you cache the fetched contacts, groups, or containers, you need to
>   refetch these objects (and release the old cached objects) when
>   CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification is posted.

Comment: What happend, when user change only phone number , email ?? so again want to check all the items again .... BTW This doc about ABAddressBookAddRecord. This was deprecated in IOS 9

Comment: Yes you have to , Please check documentation link , It has detailed description for using identifier. Identifier property is same for CNContacts too.